# отображение шрифтов font awesome

Tags: css, шрифты, fontawesome

В один момент на сайте вместо иконок font awesome стали отображаться квадратики. В элементах консоли на вкладке Вычисления в разделе Отображаемые шрифты написано *Times New Roman—Локальный файл(1 глиф)*. На сайте, который находится на другом сервере (где те же иконки отображаются нормально) в том же разделе написано *Font Awesome 5 Free—Сетевой ресурс(1 глиф)*
Но на обоих сайтах в свойствах css font-family задано значение "Font Awesome 5 Free". Почему на одном из сайтов это значение игнорируется? Или проблема в другом?
[image: проблемный сайт]
[image: работающий сайт]

Comment: В разделе сеть/network посмотрите, загрузились ли файлы шрифта в браузер. Может там ошибка

Comment: к сожалению, проблема не в этом. Информация по файлу all.min.css - Код статуса 200 OK

Comment: css - ok, а сами файлы шрифтов? voff, ttf или svg?

Comment: к сожалению не знаю про voff, ttf или svg. Может сказать о чем именно почитать, что посмотреть? Дополнительные файлы шрифтов не подключаю помимо all.min.css. Свойства со значениями voff, ttf или svg также мною нигде не используются
UPD я вижу люди подключают доп файлы с расширениями voff, ttf, но я подключаю только all.min.css. Можно попробовать отдельно эти файлы подключить?

Comment: Если all.css скачивали с сайта FA, то там в css стоит `src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }`. Т.е. по пути `../webfonts` на вашем сайте должны лежать файлы шрифтов, из скачанного архива

Comment: Вы же качали "Free for web" со страницы https://fontawesome.com/v5/download ?

Comment: И, видимо на одном сайте файлы присутствуют, а на другом нет. И браузер, не найдя файлов, заменяет их на имеющийся в системе таймс

Comment: да, вы оказались правы, путь в самом css.min я не поменял. Спасибо, отмечу ваш комментарий как решение, если оформите его как ответ